# found packages strings (build.go) and filedirs(reader.go) in /usr/local/go/src/strings

Tags: go

I almost give up, just learned go and already having problems

[image]

these are lines that causes trouble

```
s := strings.ToUpper(tmp.String())
if _, err := io.Copy(f2, strings.NewReader(s)); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

I followed tutorial from packtub. please help me how to solve it. thanks

edit:
this is what I put in .bash_profile

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/Projects/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Comment: Are you by any chance writing your source files under /usr/local/go/src/strings? Looks like you have a file (reader.go) that declares a package "filedirs" under /usr/local/go/src/strings

Comment: your setup is seriously broken. you should not have a different tree than https://golang.org/src/strings/ (assuming you run latest)

Comment: I put my project folders in /Users/yumugee/Projects/go/src/go_cookbook/

I can run the program if I remove the codes above.
@bserdar

Comment: That message above is complaining above the go stdlib source dirs. So it is possible that your setup is broken. If I were you, I'd remove /usr/local/go, reinstall go, and try again.

Comment: ok, I'll try to reinstall go. thank you very much bserdar